# PHP: json_decode(json_encode($xml));

Tags: php

I was reading some code and saw the following line

```
 $obj = json_decode(json_encode($xml));
```

`$xml` is from `simplexml_load_string` so to me it looks like that the line is equivalent of

```
$obj = $xml;
```

What might be reason for the seemingly unnecessary encoding and decoding?

Comment: If the second argument to `json_decode` was passed as true, it's a just-about-good-enough way of converting a SimpleXMLElement into a PHP array. As it stands, this turns it into stdClass, which is more or less entirely pointless.

Comment: Actually, it would require 2nd parameter for json_decode set to true, in order to return an associative array instead of object of stdClass. Apart from that, @iainn is right.

Comment: "looks like that the line is equivalent of `$obj = $xml;`" — If you just run the code you'll see is isn't true ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `$xml` is a `SimpleXml` object, you can't access some of its attributes directly. It's a trick that is used to convert `SimpleXml` object to a classical object and get access to all of its attributes :)

Also, you can pass a boolean parameter to get an array instead of an object: `json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);`

Comment: Under what circumstances can SimpleXML not access some attributes?

Comment: With SimpleXml you need to use method of it class like $xml->getChildrens() etc, it's just a trick to avoid spend time to search right function , it's easier to use it like a classical object $xml->myattributes
see documentation http://php.net/manual/fr/book.simplexml.php